Is the Wasserstein $p$-space closed in the weak topology?
Let $(X, d)$ be a Polish space, and let $\mathcal P_p(X)$ denote the Wasserstein space of order $p$, which is the set of probability measures $\mu$ on $X$ with finite $p$-th moment, i.e.,
$
\int_X d(x_0, x)^p d\mu(x) < \infty
$
for some (and hence all) $x_0 \in X$.
Suppose $(\mu_n)_{n ∈ ℕ}$ is a sequence of probability measures in $\mathcal P_p(X)$ that converges weakly to a probability measure $\mu$. Does it follow that $\mu \in \mathcal P_p(X)$?

This is claimed to be true in the proof of Lemma 2.4.2. in "An Invitation to Statistics in Wasserstein Space" (the proof is given on p. 11 of the supplementary material of the same book) as a consequence of the lower semicontinuity property
\begin{equation*}
\liminf_{n → ∞} W_p(μ_n,ν_n) \geq W_p(μ,ν) \tag{$\diamond$}
\end{equation*}
whenever $μ_n → μ$ and $ν_n → ν$ weakly, and where $W_p$ denotes the Wasserstein distance of order $p$. I don't see how $(\diamond)$ shows the claim: an idea is to set $ν_n := δ_{x_0} $ for some fixed $x_0 ∈ X$ and then observe that $ \int_X d(x_0, x)^p d\mu(x) = W_p(μ,ν)$ as well as
$$W_p(μ_n,ν_n) = W_p(μ_n,δ_{x_0}) = \int_X d(x_0, x)^p d\mu_n(x) < \infty$$ for all $n ∈ℕ $. But since the lim inf of this sequence of Wasserstein distances need not be finite, I don't see how to conclude.
Any insights would be appreciated!

I think this is false. Consider the sequence $\mu_n =(1-1/n)\delta_0 + 1/n\delta_{n^2}$. This sequence converges weakly to $\delta_0$ but its second moment is $n$ and so converges to $+\infty$.
Edit: Consider the following sequence instead $\mu_n=\rho_n(x) dx$ with
\begin{equation}
\rho_n(x)=\frac{C_n\,e^{-x^2/n}}{1+|x|^3}
\end{equation}
where the $C_n$ is the appropriate normalization constant. The sequence has finite second moment and converges to $μ = ρ(x)dx$ with
$$ ρ(x) = \frac{C}{1+|x|^3},$$
since pointwise convergence of densities implies weak convergence of measures. This limit $μ$ has an infinite second moment.

But in this case the limiting measure has finite moments of all orders, so it does not disprove the claim of weak closedness of $\mathcal P_p(X)$. I'm also sceptical, but we'd need a weak limit of measures with finite second moments which itself has no finite second moment. But this gave me an idea, I think something can be done using density wrt. the weak topology of convex combination of dirac measures in the space of all measures on $(ℝ, \mathcal B_ℝ)$....

Does the new example work?

Absolutely, nice! I've taken the liberty to add a reference for clarity.

thanks for fixing the typos :)
